# Ненужное дублирование данных при использовании фрагментов Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Помогите разобраться почему происходит дублирование данных при нажатии кнопки "назад" телефона, тоесть имеем список из 12 полей, при переходе с главного фрагмента в дочерний и затем обратно список уже имеет 24 поле, повторяем те же действия и список уже 36 полей и так можно пока наверное память не закончится.

**HeroesFragment**

```
 class HeroesFragment : Fragment() {

    private var mBinding: FragmentHeroesBinding? = null

    private lateinit var mAllInfoApex: HeroesViewModel

    private lateinit var mHeroesAdapter: HeroesAdapter

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
            mBinding = FragmentHeroesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            return mBinding!!.root
    }
     override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        mAllInfoApex =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HeroesViewModel::class.java)

        mAllInfoApex.getAllInfoApexFromAPI(Constants.API_PLAYER_VALUE)

        mBinding?.rvHeroList?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireActivity(), 2)

        mHeroesAdapter = HeroesAdapter(this@HeroesFragment)

        mBinding?.rvHeroList?.adapter = mHeroesAdapter

        InfoApexViewModelObserver()
    }
        fun heroesDetails(legends: Heroes){
        findNavController().navigate(HeroesFragmentDirections.actionAllHeroesToHeroesDetails(legends))
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_profile, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }
        override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mBinding = null
    }
}
```

**DetailsHeroesFragment**

```
class DetailsHeroesFragment : Fragment() {

    private var mBinding: FragmentDetailsHeroesBinding? = null

    //private val hero : ArrayList<AllHeroes.Data>? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        mBinding = FragmentDetailsHeroesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return mBinding!!.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val args: DetailsHeroesFragmentArgs by navArgs()

        Glide.with(this)
            .load(args.heroesDetails.data.ImgAssets.banner)
            .into(mBinding!!.ivHeroesDetails)

        mBinding!!.tvHeroesName.text = args.heroesDetails.name

        args.heroesDetails.data.let { values ->
            when {
                values.data.isNullOrEmpty() -> {
                    mBinding!!.tvDataName.text = "NOT DATA"

                    mBinding!!.tvDataValue.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    mBinding!!.tvDataName2.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    mBinding!!.tvDataValue2.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    mBinding!!.tvDataName3.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    mBinding!!.tvDataValue3.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    mBinding!!.tvDataName4.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    mBinding!!.tvDataValue4.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                    Log.i("Heroes test", "test")
                }
  else -> {
                    mBinding!!.tvDataName.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                    mBinding!!.tvDataValue.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    mBinding!!.tvDataName2.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    mBinding!!.tvDataValue2.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    mBinding!!.tvDataName3.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    mBinding!!.tvDataValue3.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    mBinding!!.tvDataName4.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    mBinding!!.tvDataValue4.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mBinding = null
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var mNavController: NavController


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        mBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(mBinding.root)

        mNavController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_all_heroes,
                R.id.navigation_match_history,
                R.id.navigation_funny_videos
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(mNavController, appBarConfiguration)
        mBinding.navView.setupWithNavController(mNavController)

    }
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(mNavController, null)
    }    
}
```

Тоесть получается когда возвращаюсь из DetailsHeroesFragment обратно к HeroesFragment то к существующим данным добавляется список еще точно таких же данных, как это пофиксить ? Либо где я что-то упустил ? В логах вижу как данные создаются 2 раза затем при переходе еще +2 и т.д
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ViewModel**

```
class HeroesViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val allInfoApexAPIService = AllInfoApexAPIService()

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    val loadAllInfoApex = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val allInfoApexResponse = MutableLiveData<AllHeroes.Heroes>()
    val allInfoApexLoadingError = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    fun getAllInfoApexFromAPI(username: String){
        loadAllInfoApex.value = true

        compositeDisposable.add(
            allInfoApexAPIService.getAllInfoApexTracker(player = username)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(object: DisposableSingleObserver<AllHeroes.Heroes>(){
                    override fun onSuccess(value: AllHeroes.Heroes) {
                        loadAllInfoApex.value = false
                        allInfoApexResponse.value = value
                        allInfoApexLoadingError.value = false

                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        loadAllInfoApex.value = false
                        allInfoApexLoadingError.value = true
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }

                })
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При переходе во второй фрагмент уничтожается View в первом фрагменте и при возврате в первый у вас снова создаётся View, те вызываются `onCreateView`,  `onViewCreated` и `mAllInfoApex.getAllInfoApexFromAPI` соответственно. Вероятно в этом дело. Одно из решений - это перенести вызов `getAllInfoApexFromAPI` в `init` блок `ViewModel`

Comment: Буду пробовать, спасибо, как получиться закрою тему, добавлю выше код из самой viewModel

Comment: не совсем понимаю как передать username в init

Comment: @Ethernets так у вас константа какая-то используется, `getAllInfoApexFromAPI(Constants.API_PLAYER_VALUE)`

Comment: да верно, уже и забыл про её существование